# Problems with an specific dataframe: dropping columns, multiplying by another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some issues with a dataframe. I haven't found out the reason.

The dataframe in question is this one:

```
igc_df
Out[30]: 
              1990        1991        1992   ...       2016        2017        2018 
NUTS_ID                                      ...                                    
AT        18771.250   18171.750   18024.000  ...   30351.561   30927.367   32107.263
BE        33522.718   30195.996   31435.236  ...   44326.861   46496.095   46913.188
BG        22393.000   18779.750   15810.750  ...   10697.000   10802.369   10406.698
CZ        28111.000   24096.250   35143.000  ...   23437.068   24897.500   23535.981
DE       198253.000  197062.750  200869.750  ...  232503.925  242876.975  228012.980
DK         6217.500    6690.000    6831.000  ...    7704.542    7997.867    8323.611
EE         2223.250    2450.000    1752.500  ...    1238.500    1110.118    1267.871
EL            0.000       0.000       0.000  ...    6410.250    3745.790    3727.916
ES        39517.064   40557.302   43034.262  ...   75955.126   88028.467   96724.751
FI        10666.000   11446.500   11961.500  ...    6173.572    6528.092    6235.882
FR       106880.792  113685.750  113871.812  ...  113767.099  108666.701  112559.033
HR         7242.750    6099.000    5548.000  ...    4149.750    4494.614    4454.127
HU        37268.750   31098.500   25024.750  ...   15058.357   15840.000   16715.750
IE         4159.500    4377.097    4045.500  ...    8757.936    8862.000    9165.889
IT       150847.750  152795.000  155315.500  ...   97249.250  103164.981  100589.290
LT        10304.250   10895.250    6181.250  ...    3346.500    3392.544    3618.725
LU         3247.250    3254.500    3444.500  ...    3265.548    3090.219    3219.427
LV         5108.250    4443.500    3781.500  ...    1251.489    1250.819    1323.170
NL        78810.487   81238.479   81305.229  ...   58969.915   61468.253   59472.327
PL        29174.750   22070.250   19621.000  ...   39668.250   42851.520   45467.179
PT            0.000       0.000       0.000  ...   13027.685   14120.138   14504.115
RO       194994.750  133018.750   39247.750  ...   24241.750   25918.179   26534.496
SE         2940.500    2486.500    2307.000  ...    3370.250    3010.294    3928.018
SI         6602.000    5805.000    4615.750  ...    4832.000    5102.013    5412.363
SK        15506.750   13708.000   15528.000  ...    9215.750    9942.250   10321.792
UK       121002.500  125588.750  121359.750  ...   90298.784   92721.167   94460.574

[26 rows x 29 columns]
```

Doing `igc_df.dtypes` I get that the dataframe contains `float`:

```
igc_df.dtypes
Out[31]: 
1990     float64
1991     float64
1992     float64
1993     float64
1994     float64
1995     float64
1996     float64
1997     float64
1998     float64
1999     float64
2000     float64
2001     float64
2002     float64
2003     float64
2004     float64
2005     float64
2006     float64
2007     float64
2008     float64
2009     float64
2010     float64
2011     float64
2012     float64
2013     float64
2014     float64
2015     float64
2016     float64
2017     float64
2018     float64
dtype: object
```

I tried to drop columns from the dataframe, but, as an example, when I do `igc_df.drop(columns=1990,inplace=True)`, I get `KeyError: '[1990] not found in axis'`.
Also, when I try to multiply another float64 dataframe by this one using `.mul(igc_df)`, the result is a dataframe filled with NaN.

The dataframe came from an Object dataframe I converted to `float64` using `igc_df=igc_df.apply(pd.to_numeric)`.

Any ideas on where can the problem be? I'd appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `dtype` shows you the type of the **contents** of the column not the column name, you should probably try

```py
igc_df.drop(columns=["1990"], inplace=True)
```

For the multiplication, can you share the exact code that you used to multiply ?